# Sata drives not recognized in BIOS after motherboard change

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, sata, hardware-detection

I just changed out the motherboard, CPU and PSU in my desktop, and now no sata drives are being recognized on system boot. I have double checked the connections, and both the data and power cables are fine to all three sata-connected drives.

When in the bios, I see "no bootable device found" under "boot sequence", and "no device found" under the "SATA" menu.

I have tried using the legacy setting for storage boot option control, and nothing changed.

for reference, the new mobo is the Gigabyte Z390UD.

Comment: Can you start in BIOS, reset BIOS to Defaults, save, exit, restart and then see if the drive is recognized.

Comment: Just tried, nothing changed.

Comment: The motherboard may be too different. Try a new, empty, blank drive to see if that works or there is a different complication.

Comment: Just check if there's any option to Enable/Disable SATA Controller in BIOS/UEFI. If so make sure that it's enabled. Then set SATA mode to AHCI if such an option exists and try again. This time connect only one SATA  drive to port 0 and check. Also Disable Fast Boot option if it's found to be Enabled. Some Gigabyte boards have an option to disable SATA drives except OS drive (Last Boot HDD) with Fast Boot On.

Comment: Try with just one drive connected at a time, make sure your boot drive appears in the BIOS. Check boot order. Legacy mode (non-UEFI) may be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that all my drives got fried by a power spike. I had to replace them with new ones and that worked fine; just an unfortunate thing to happen.